# Метод wall.post отправляет на стену несколько одинаковых сообщений (VK API)

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Отправляет на стену хорошо, только создаёт несколько записей:

[image]

Функцию вызываю один раз. Есть какие-то мысли?

```
class vk {
private static $class = null;

public static function create(){
    if(!self::$class){
        self::$class = new vk();
    }
    return self::$class;
}

function postWall($text, array $params = null){        
    if($params['image']){
        //приложение узнаёт http-адрес для загрузки фотографии на стену
        $response = self::doQuery('photos.getWallUploadServer', ['group_id' => $this->group_id]);

        //Приложение формирует POST-запрос на полученный адрес. Запрос должен включать поле photo, содержащее файл с изображением (JPG, PNG, BMP или GIF) 
        $curl = self::doQueryCurl($params['image'], $response);

        //С помощью метода photos.saveWallPhoto приложение передаёт серверу полученные данные и получает данные о загруженной фотографии.
        $photo = self::doQuery('photos.saveWallPhoto',[
            'server' => $curl->server,
            'photo' => $curl->photo,
            'hash' => $curl->hash,
            'group_id' => $this->group_id,
        ]);        
        $photo = $photo['response'][0]['id'];
        $params['image'] = $photo;
    }

    //формирование параметров для публикации на стене
    $attachments = implode(',', $params);

    //публикует новую запись на своей или чужой стене
    $wall = self::doQuery('wall.post', [
        'owner_id' => '-'.$this->group_id,
        'friends_only' => 0,
        'from_group' => 1,
        'message' => $text,
        'attachments' => $attachments
    ]);
    var_dump($wall);
    return $wall;
}

public function doQuery($method, array $arrParams = []){
    //начальные параметры
    $initParams = [
        'access_token' => $this->accesstoken,//токен для выполнения допустимых методов (нужен не везде)
    ];
    //слить массивы
    $params = array_merge_recursive($arrParams,$initParams);
    //подготовка url
    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/'.$method.'?'.urldecode(http_build_query($params));
    //выполнение запроса и получение ответа
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    //вернуть результат
    return $result;
}

protected function doQueryCurl($pathImg, $response) {
    $file = new CURLFile(realpath(Yii::$app->basePath).$pathImg);//подготовка файла к отправке (/../uploads/)

    if (!isset($response->error)) 
        $ch = curl_init($response['response']['upload_url']);
    else 
        return $response;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'photo' => $file,
    ));
    if (($upload = curl_exec($ch)) === false) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    $upload = json_decode($upload);

    return $upload;
} 
}   


$vk = new vk();`$vk->postWall('test',[
'image' => путь фото,
'link' => ссылка,
]);`
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос Ваш код.

Comment: Сам пхп-файл запускается несколько раз небось

Comment: Та же ситуация. Нашли причину?